# Мутации React + Apollo

Tags: javascript, foreach, graphql

Пытаюсь сделать запрос для добавления новой записи в базу данных graphql с помощю React + Apollo. Проблема в том, что запрос, вроде как выполняется, но в базу ничего не падает.

Компонент с добавлением.

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import './style.css'
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Mutation } from "react-apollo";

const ADD_REGION = gql`
mutation AddRegion($reg: String!) {
addRegion(name: $reg) {
    region {
        name
    }
}
}
    `;

class AddRegion extends PureComponent{

render(){
    return (
        <Mutation mutation={ADD_REGION}>
            {(mutate, { loading, error, data }) => {
                if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
                if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;
                if (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }

                return (
                    <button onClick={
                        () => mutate(
                            {
                                variables:
                                    {reg: 'Dooms'}
                            }
                        )
                    }>
                        Добавить регион
                    </button>
                );
            }}
        </Mutation>        );
}
}

export default AddRegion
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from "./components/App";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import {InMemoryCache} from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({
cache: new InMemoryCache(),
uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/',
// fetchOptions: {
//     // method: 'POST',
//     mode: 'no-cors',
// },
// headers: {
//     // 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': Cookie.get('csrf'),
// },
});

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App/>
    </ApolloProvider>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Не хватает кода серверной части graphQL, "вроде как выполняется" - не пойдет, нужно отладчиком пройтись по ресолверам (resolvers) мутации и найти там ошибку. Покажи код сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё работает. Ошибка была в том, что я, хлеб, и смотрел добавления на развёрнутом сервере, в то время как добавлял на локальный